# Implementing a Blockchain at the very basic level?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, project

My question may sound a bit confusing so a bit of a background is in order. I am doing my Computer Engineering Final Year Project related to parallel processing and GPGPUs. i'll be working on implementing the Blockchain architecture on GPGPUs.

To find the initial point of my project , my advisor has asked me to 'implement' the block chain.

Now , being an undergraduate and a beginner at all this , it sounded quite confusing to me. However , after some research , i have found that you can 'fork' the bitcoin core for implementing the blockchain.

However , i am not the most prodigious coder and have more affinity with hardware aspects. so i need some help in deciding how to implement the blockchain on a very simple level , as in , what's the most basic coding task/basic operation i have to do to atleast start the implementation or establishment of a blockchain.

kindly do help me out , as i have been handed a very tight deadline by my advisor

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core is a software which maintains the blockchain ledger, You can obviously fork it and go through the entire code and make some changes to the source code to make your own blockchain (This is what every blockchain company is doing nowadays under the pretext of creating blockchain technologies.)

However, the above mentioned task is really time consuming. What you can do is study the workings of the bitcoin blockchain, and simulate them using a more popular database. There have been cases where people have sold their 'blockchain' technology with SQL running at the back. Blockchain is basically a database(highly replicated) and you shouldnt confuse it with anything else.

So trying to make a blockchain from scratch will obviously take a lot of time in learning and then coding. If you are going with the "hidden SQL" blockchain , or for that matter any other db, you would need to make APIs to access the blockchain(just like bitcoin core). You dont need to have all the API's obviously, but the ones which are crucial for the blockchain you'll have to emulate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try working on **[Multichain](http://multichain.com)**  to implement a blockchain. You can fiddle with the provided parameters as per your requirement.

**Tip:** *Run it on Linux even if it's on a VM.*